# Visual studio autofit fontsize DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

How can I make the datagridview autosize the fontsize so it will fit?

[image: My gridview]

Comment: maybe this will help
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizerowsmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you trying to make the text bigger so it fills the column's width, or are you trying to make the column width smaller so it fits the text?

Comment: Im trying to make it fit the width of the dgw, so the all the content smaller.

Comment: The AutoSizeColumnsMode property can help.  There does get to be a point where the grid is just getting unusable of course.

Answer (score -1):

Use the columns property of the data grid  and set width of each column accordingly . 
Also you can have autosize proerty enabled/disable as per ur requirement .. That will definately solve ur purpose.. Plz vote Up if you find it useful. .Happy Coding . :)